# Disable scrolling between elements, but allow within child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code in jQuery to disable scrolling between elements identified with an id.

```
$('#element-1').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
 return false;
})
```

But this impedes scrolling when the content inside the element is longer than the viewport. How can I allow this?

```
<div class="container" id="element-1">
 <div class="row">
    <div>This is one row inside of element 1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div>This is another row inside of element 1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <!-- I can no longer see this because I can't scroll! -->
    <div>Just another row inside of element 1</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="element-2">
 <div class="row">
    <div>This is one row inside of element 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div>This is another row inside of element 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div>Just another row inside of element 2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any css is applied for the divs like `overflow:scroll`, `height` and `width`, if not try

Comment: I tried, but still no. I checked and there are no specific heights on any of the divs either.